# Window 7 laptop weird wifi problems

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

Laptop with intel centrino adapter has a problem. It does not remember saved networks so everytime you join a network you have to type the password, if it even allows you to connect. I found sometimes after entering the password it instantly comes back with a failed attempt. I can see under managed networks the wifi I'm currently connected to but as soon as I switch to another network it disappears from that list.

I installed the latest drivers and ran the diagnostics. It failed at the Association test but not sure how to interpret that. Another strange thing is it only seems to be happening under this one user on the computer. I signed in as my account and was able to switch and maintain wifi networks.

I'm not sure what to troubleshoot next and looking for leads. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried: `chdksk`? `sfc`?  Blowing away the troublesome user (and their profile) and recreating their user account?

Comment: It had not occured to me to run chdsk or sfc for a wifi issue but I will give that a try. While I suspected it to be a user profile issue, I am not all that familiar with the process to recreat the user account, at least not without losing everything.